# setAlpha of UIBarButtonItem is not working in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a rightBarButtonItem with a button. I changed the alpha of button in viewDidLoad, but it is not come in appearance. Why? if i set this to any action (touch event) its working fine. How to solve this problem and why its not working in ViewDidLoad?

Answer (score 6):

UIKit automatically resets the alpha value of UIBarButtonItems. To have it disappear you actually need to remove it altogether by setting `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem` to `nil`. If you just want some transparency you need to have it on an image that you'll set as the barButtonItem background (for this you can use the `appearance` proxy.

Comment: actually my question is, when i set alpha to 0.0f on viewDidLoad its not working. i mean its appeared, i want it to be disappeared by setting alpha to 0.0f.

Comment: What I meant is that UIKit doesn't allow you to set the alpha of UIBarButtonItem to 0. You simply cannot hide it: you need to remove it from the bar instead. Even if you use a custom view for your button and you set the custom view's alpha to 0, you won't have the desired effect as it will be reset by UIKit when laying out the button.

Comment: its Ok. But in an IBACTION i set my custom View's (UIBarButtonItem) alpha to 0.0f. Its working fine. So its possible.please reply.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to set the alpha value for a UIBarButtonItem.  To do it you need to create a UIButton and then set it as the view of the UIBarButtonItem.  Here is an example:

```
UIButton *pauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[pauseButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pause", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[pauseButton sizeToFit];
[pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pauseButton.titleLabel.alpha = 0; /* set this alpha to whatever you like */
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:pauseButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` sets the alpha of the `customView` property of `UIBarButtonItem` automatically, but you can override and enforce your desired alpha using a custom class. (If you want a semi-transparent button).

```
// For use in UIBarButtonItem - UIKit resets the alpha of custom views automatically
final class HalfTransparentButton: UIButton {
    override var alpha: CGFloat {
        set { super.alpha = 0.5 }
        get { return 0.5 }
    }
}
```